# Is there an official name for Metro-Style apps?

Tags: windows-8

Is there an official name for the apps that are found in Windows Store? They were previously called Metro-Style apps. But now it seems they are being called Modern UI apps or Windows Store apps.

Comment: We call them Windows Store apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, according to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Windows_Store_and_Apps)

> Soma Somasegar (vice president of Microsoft's development software division) officially confirmed that "Windows Store apps" would be the official term for the apps

the official term for the apps is **Windows Store apps**

Comment: I think it's very obvious where Microsoft is heading with the OS if they are naming the UI-style "store"... :P

Answer (score 4):

They are called "Windows Store Apps" – nothing very fancy.

- [The Windows Store | Microsoft](http://www.windowsstore.com/)
- [Windows Store - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store)

Answer (score 0):

The official term is "Windows Store App" or "Modern UI App".